# Firestore onAuthStateChanged and users in a subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app where users can authenticate, in Firestore I save extra data from that user (username, age).

Now in my app, users are coupled to events, I chose to have an **events** collection, which has a **users** subcollection.

I'm using the firebase `onAuthStateChanged` listener to see when my user has logged in. However the issue I'm not facing is, to get the firestore data for my user, I need to know which event this user belongs to, which is of course, data I do not have access to at the time the user signs in, for example:

```js
const onAuthStateChangedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser !== null) {
            const user = await getDoc(doc(db, 'events/${eventId}/users', id))
            useAuth().user = user
            return resolve(user)
        }
        return resolve(null)
    }, err => {
        reject(err)
    })
})
```

In the example above, to get my user's data, I need to know the **eventId**, which I can not possible determine from the authenticated user.

I'm wondering how to achieve this?

- I could save the eventId in localStorage as soon as the user registers, but that can cause issue's, since the complete app then relies on something being set on localStorage

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to solve this would be to add the UID of the user in a field inside the `events/${eventId}/users` documents and then use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all `users` collections. This will give you a list of all event/users docs for that user.

To find the event for such an event/user doc, you first take the `DocumentReference` for the `DocumentSnapshot` and then go up the `parent` chain twice to get to the parent `event` document.

Comment: Thanks, for a while I thought the subcollection is the way to go here, but wouldn't this all be easier if I just have flat structure? So not nesting the users inside the event, but adding an eventId column to the users column?

Comment: That may lead to write hot spots sooner than if you separate the users per subcollection of the event doc. But honestly given the index the collection group query requires the difference is probably gonna be quite small.

Comment: So you mean the collection group query + subcollection method isn't better then the root collection idea? Or which one would you recommend?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing your full list of (current and future) use-cases. Early on, I doubt the difference is going to be big, and (once you accept data duplication, as you seem to have) it's typically not hard to switch between them (just possibly time-consuming if its a lot of docs).

Comment: Thanks for getting back Frank! The two most important queries are going to be "Get all photos, by all users for this event", and "get all user photos for this event", the three most important columns being events, users, photos